# Problema para marcar e deletar um elemento especifico de um array

Tags: javascript, html, css, array, funções

Esou fazendo uma To-Do list simples em js. Quero adicionar a função para deletar um item ja criado.

O codigo escrito foi esse:

```
function renderTasks(){
    const list = document.getElementById('task-list');
    list.innerHTML = '';

    tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = task;
    
        let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
        removeButton.textContent = 'Remove';
        removeButton.classList.add('btn-remove');
        removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => removeTask(index)); // Usando uma função de callback
        li.appendChild(removeButton);
    
        list.appendChild(li);
    })
}

function removeTask(index){
    tasks.splice(index , 1)
    renderTasks()
}
```

Porem ele sempre deleta o ultimo elemento adicionado e não o elemento em que o botão foi clicado, como resolver??

Answer (score -2):

Quando o evento é chamado a variável index já foi incrementada para a última iteração. Terias que criar uma função à parte para renderizar cada tarefa dentro do ciclo.

```
function renderTasks(){
    const list = document.getElementById('task-list');
    list.innerHTML = '';

    tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
        renderTask(list, task, index);
    })
}

function renderTask(list, task, index) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = task;

    let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.textContent = 'Remove';
    removeButton.classList.add('btn-remove');
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => removeTask(index)); // Usando uma função de callback
    li.appendChild(removeButton);

    list.appendChild(li);
}

function removeTask(index){
    tasks.splice(index , 1)
    renderTasks()
}
```